# MVC template editor how to display items from two model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I hope I explain this correctly..
What I am trying to do is build up a session array with a list of products in.
Then display these on a form in text boxes with quantiles next to them and be able to submit them. I think I need to use template editor. But I don't know how to put data into the list of items.

This is how my session variable is currently being populated..

```
 IList<EnqProduct> items2 = Session["enquiry"] as IList<EnqProduct>;
 desc = desc.Replace(",", "");
 EnqProduct item = new EnqProduct();
 item.Id = (items2.Count + 1).ToString();
 item.Product = desc;
 item.Quantity = "0";
 items2.Add(item);
```

So desc, can be productone, product two etc.

Enquiry Product model:

```
namespace MvcEditorTemplates.Models
{
    public class EnqProduct
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

Normal Enquiry Model:

```
public class Enquiry
{ 
   public List<EnqProduct> EnqProduct { get; set; }
}
```

How i am trying to populate the model, but this is static. I need it to be populated from the array items:

```
var EnquiryModel = new Enquiry { 
EnqProduct = items2.Select(c => new EnqProduct()
{
       Quantity = c.Quantity,
       Product = c.Product
 })    
};
```

Enquiry product template view:

```
   @model MvcEditorTemplates.Models.EnqProduct
<div class="fl">
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Product)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Product)
    </p>   
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Quantity)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Quantity)
    </p>  
</div>
```

This is how im trying to get it to be displayed din the view:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnqProduct)
```

EDIT:

at  `items2.Select(c => new EnqProduct()`

i get a IEnumerbale error something about cast?

Comment: If you want to display data from two models, just create a combined ViewModel that has two properties; one for each Model.

Comment: I need it to be submitted back aswel, and the list of products is dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public class ErrorMessage
{
    public DateTime ErrorDate { get; set; }
    public string ErrorText { get; set; }
    public int DexRowId { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    public string Processed { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public int DexRowID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
public class Result
{
    public List<ErrorMessage> errorMessageList { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction> transactionList { get; set; }

}
```

In your controller:

```
List<Transaction> transactionList = ...;//query to populate your list;
List<ErrorMessage> errorMessageList = ...;//query to populate your list;

Result result = new Result();
result.ErrorMessageList = errorMessageList;
result.TransactionList = transactionList;

return View(result);
```

and in your view:

```
@model Models.Result
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Result";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ResultLayout.cshtml";
}
```

EDIT:

```
@model IENumerable<MvcEditorTemplates.Models.EnqProduct>
@{
foreach( EnqProduct ep in @model)
{
  .... your code comes here.........
}
}
```

Comment: I think this is similar to what i am trying to do already, im trying to view a list of products throught my enquiry model, but how do i populate each different one

Comment: if your view accepts list of @ model MvcEditorTemplates.Models.EnqProduct than you should use @ model IENumerable<MvcEditorTemplates.Models.EnqProduct> rather or you can pass EnqProduct in model. you can display list by using foreach loop, see my edit